# I am trying to get a script that shows details of currently logged in user

Tags: powershell

I am very new to PowerShell.

I am looking to roll out a script that will show up on user's workstation something like "My Info". This will be a script that looks up and displays information about currently logged in user. This script will display the following on a browser.

[image: Image of the expected output]

The reason of showing this link on a browser is so that, I can add some text that guides the user to catalog items such as How to extend account expiration date, how to update my info, etc.

I found the following script [from here](https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-script-to-display-information-about-active-directory-users/) but I am not able to get it to run for the currently logged in user and the output to HTML.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 1)]
        [string]$UserName
    )
    #Import AD Module
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    $Employee = Get-ADuser $UserName -Properties *, 'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed'
    $Manager = ((Get-ADUser $Employee.manager).samaccountname)
    $PasswordExpiry = [datetime]::FromFileTime($Employee.'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed')
      $AccountInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
        First_Name    = $Employee.GivenName
        Last_Name     = $Employee.Surname
        Title        = $Employee.Title
        Department   = $Employee.department
        Manager      = $Manager
        City         = $Employee.city
        Employee_Number   = $Employee.employeeNumber
        User_Name     = $Employee.SamAccountName
        Display_Name   = $Employee.displayname
        Email_Address = $Employee.emailaddress
        Office_Phone  = $Employee.officephone
        Mobile_Phone  = $Employee.mobilephone
    }
    $AccountStatus = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Password_Expired       = $Employee.PasswordExpired
        Account_Locked_Out      = $Employee.LockedOut
        Lock_Out_Time           = $Employee.AccountLockoutTime
        Account_Enabled        = $Employee.Enabled
        Account_Expiration_Date = $Employee.AccountExpirationDate
        Password_Last_Set       = $Employee.PasswordLastSet
        Password_ExpireDate    = $PasswordExpiry
    }
    $AccountInfo
    $AccountStatus
```

The script above shows a prompt for username. I don't want that. I would like it to run for the currently logged in user.
Edit:-
As @harrymc pointed out, I think, I will skip the idea of the output showing up in HTML format.
If it isn't too much, can someone show me how the code above can be updated to just show details of the current user?

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Please [edit] and add these to the question.

Comment: Why is this tagged PowerShell when what you obviously need is ASP.NET or a similar technology?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense : Browsers execute in a sandbox and cannot call PowerShell and access operating system calls. PowerShell is not a browser technology.

Comment: @harrymc
My bad, I mean when a user executes this script, the output is shown on a browser.
I know that powershell can output files in a txt or CSV format. I was wondering if HTML is a possibility.

Comment: Yes, certainly, HTML file is a text file, but you need to build it all, header and body.  PowerShell won't do all that automatically.

Comment: Look up system environment variables that show the currently logged in user: this is where a PowerShell script can get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can automatically convert powershell objects to bare-bones HTML pages with [ConvertTo-HTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html).

```sh
$AccountInfo,$AccountStatus |
  ConvertTo-Html -as List |
  Out-File 'C:\folder\temp.html'

# open html file in default browser
Start-Process 'file:///C:/folder/temp.html'
```

There are some options like formatting as a table, or including a css stylesheet if you want it to look better

As in the other answer, `$env:USERNAME` will return the current user's username. To get the script to stop asking for the username, change the parameter slightly like this, and the default value will be the current user:

```
Param(
  [string]$UserName = $env:USERNAME
)
```

---

If you plan to have users run the file themselves, they may not have RSAT installed, so active directory cmdlets like `Get-ADUser` would need to be changed slightly. Try something like this:

```
$searcher = [adsisearcher]"(&(objectClass=user)(SamAccountName=$($env:USERNAME)))"
$ADUser = $searcher.FindOne()

# Example: use the actual AD Attribute names like 'sn' for Surname
$AccountInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
    First_Name = $ADUser.Properties.givenname[0]
    Last_Name  = $ADUser.Properties.sn[0]
    Title      = $ADUser.properties.title[0]
    Department = $ADUser.properties.department[0]
}
```

Comment: This is a cool trick I did not know about. .. that is the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell function that you found will do the job of finding these
details if you call it with the current user-name.

You can get that name and other context details by :

```
$env:UserName
$env:UserDomain
$env:ComputerName
```

See
[How do I get the current username in Windows PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085744/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-windows-powershell)

If your aim is to generate an HTML file, an HTML file is nothing else
than a text file, but you need to build it all, header and body.
PowerShell won't do all that automatically for you.

Comment: I realize my mistake.
The script I posted above has everything I am looking for. The only problem is, when it is run, it asks for username. I don't want it to do that, I just want it to run for the currently logged in user and it displays the info.

Comment: @TCHTank - You will have to code PowerShell code to iterate through the domain users. Code in the question appears to attempt to retrieve the AD object that matches the user logged in. It appears your question is more of a SO question, but more debugging information, would have to be provided regardless of a migration happens. The mandatory Parameter is the source of the dialogue

Comment: My answer tells you how to easily get the current user name. That's all you need.